# How do I save a character from a file line into a character array?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I'm trying to make a decryption program, where I have a file that takes in characters that need to be replaced (replace.txt).
The example contents of replace.txt are as follows:

```
a X
b Y
c A
d C 
e I
f K
g J
h L
i P
```

... and so on.

Now, I'm trying to read in these lines and save the original character (a) and the replace character (X), going off the first line of replace.txt. However, I'm only able to read in the replace character and I can't save the original character into an array.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE * file;
  FILE * fileTwo;
  file = fopen("in.txt","rt"); // This is the encrypted text file
  fileTwo = fopen("replace.txt","rt");
  char line[4];
  char replaceChar[1];
  char orginialChar[1];
    while(fgets(line, 4, fileTwo) != NULL) {
      strtok(line, " ");
      printf("The line is: %s \n",line);
      strcpy(originalChar, &line[0]); // Trying to get the "a"
      strcpy(replaceChar, &line[2]); // Trying to get the "X"
      printf("Original Char is: %s \n",originalChar);
      printf("Replace Char is: %s \n",replaceChar);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

The output for the first run is:

```
The line is: a
Original Char is: 
Replace Char is: X
```

And it completely falls apart after that. How could I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you so mean with your array size? Remember that `fgets` reads any `newline` too. So 3 characters plus a newline plus a nul terminator makes 5, but your array is only 4. So the `newline` will be put on the next line you read.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile. Please paste the actual code you used for your first run.

Comment: Also your 1-length strings have room for *only* the nul terminator.

Comment: `strcpy(originalChar, &line[0])` is actually just `char originalChar=line[0];`. No `strtok` or other string handling functions required.

Comment: Alright, I fixed that, thanks! Now it's just back to not picking up the original character. And I think I fixed the compile issue, I didn't add in semicolons for strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was increase the size of fgets and my line array to 5 instead of 3, so the new line and null character could be added on, without doing that, the file would be read completely wrong.

Then, I had to increase the size of the original character and replace character arrays to [2], to allow the null terminator character to be added on.

Comment: I suggest that when developing you be more generous with the string lengths. Make them all 100 length to begin with. There are only three character arrays. You are not short of memory are you?

Comment: No, I am not. Thank you for the advice!